RStudio can't open specific project: system error 10053
I am using Windows 10. I recently tried to update R from 4.3.0 to the current version 4.4.1. Since then, I can't open one of my projects anymore. This project uses version control (GitLab) which I connected via SSH key. All other projects, normal R scripts in Rstudio and opening R itself work fine.
The failure report states: "An existing connection was terminated by the host computer
by the host computer".
Is there a way to reconnect to the project?.
R Session Startup Failure Report
RStudio Version
RStudio 2024.04.2+764 "Chocolate Cosmos " (e4392fc9, 2024-06-05) for windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2024.04.2+764 Chrome/120.0.6099.291 Electron/28.3.1 Safari/537.36
Error message
[No error available]
Process Output
The R session exited with code 3221225477.
Error output:
[No errors emitted]

Standard output:
[No output emitted]

Logs
C:/Users/Helga/AppData/Local/RStudio/log/rsession-Helga.log
durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen) [request-uri: /events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide-os-windows\rel-chocolate-cosmos\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:156; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide-os-windows\rel-chocolate-cosmos\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:161
2024-07-24T08:14:26.093567Z [rsession-Helga] ERROR system error 10053 (Eine bestehende Verbindung wurde softwaregesteuert
durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen) [request-uri: /events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide-os-windows\rel-chocolate-cosmos\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:156; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide-os-windows\rel-chocolate-cosmos\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:161


I tried reinstalling the old R Version, reinstalling Rstudio and to remove all startup files such as .Rprofile, .Renviron, and .RData from your initial working directory but they problem remains. I dont have any firewall, proxy settings and antimalware which should hinder Rstudio.

For me it worked when I ran RStudio as an administrator. I still don't get why it doesn't work when starting RStudio "normally", but at least now I can work again. When I reinstalled RStudio and R, it didn't work either.
